# Elixir process limit?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to create an Elixir code similar to this:

```
def infinite_loop(created_workers \\ []) do
  case next_from_queue do
    {:ok, queue_msg} ->
      new_worker = Task.async(fn -> crawling(queue_msg) end)
      infinite_loop([new_worker | created_workers])
    {:error, :empty} ->
      created_workers.map(&Task.await/1)
  end
end
```

Assuming that:

1. The `crawling` function will create another 3 `Task`
2. Every `crawling` **worker** could spend 3 seconds running
3. The `queue` could have millions of messages

How can I know what is the limit of parallel process on Elixir? How can I manage it to don't break?

Comment: Why would you not leverage [Genstage](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/GenStage.html) for this? It provides a back-pressure mechanism where the consumer will only demand further tasks from the producer as it is available. You can configure it such that consumers will spawn up dynamically as more work needs to be done. In this way, you can maximize the utility of your resources without exploding so to say.

Comment: @KevinJohnson the GenStage looks amazing!!!
However, if I didn't get it wrong, for "consume" what my producer(the queue) gets, I need to "initialize" a producer.

So, I would like you help me with the following questions:
  - Do I need to initialize multiple producers to reach more parallelism?
  - Can I do that dynamically? I mean create more producers when I have on the consumer more "waiting" jobs...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

I'd recommend using `Task.async_stream` for this. `Task.async_stream` allows you to process a stream in parallel while limiting the number of tasks that are run in parallel. While the default limit on the number of processes is 262144 in Erlang 20, if you're crawling a site, you probably want a much lower limit.

You can create a stream from a function that keeps returning new items using `Stream.iterate`:

```
stream =
  Stream.iterate(next_from_queue(), fn _ -> next_from_queue() end)
  |> Stream.take_while(fn {:ok, _} -> true; {:error, :empty} -> false end)
```

Since you want to stop at `{:error, :empty}`, we use `Stream.take_while` to stop the stream.

Then use `Task.async_stream` like this:

```
stream
|> Task.async_stream(fn {:ok, queue_msg} ->
  crawling(queue_msg)
end, max_concurrency: 16)
```

This will run the stream with a maximum of 16 tasks in parallel. The end result will be a list of all return values of `crawling(queue_msg)`.

Comment: Thanks @Dogbert for your great reply!!! I really like your approach.
However, I would like to have an elixir architecture where the code can explodes the 100% of CPU and memory.

Do you think that is a good approach spawns has many process and then catch the "limit reached exception"?

Comment: Unfortunately @AugustoPedraza, there would be no case of "raising exception" when reaching the limit of what BEAM virtual machine can handle. It would just simply crash.